# Dropwizard log deletion doesnt work with archivedFileCount set

Tags: logback, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard service and I have following appender config for dropwizard:

```
    appenders=[
    {
        archive=true
        archivedFileCount=700
        archivedLogFilenamePattern="/logs/my-service/application.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log.gz"
        currentLogFilename="/logs/my-service/application.log"
        logFormat="%-5level %date{ISO8601, UTC} %mdc{opc-request-id} [%thread] %logger: %message%n"
        timeZone=UTC
        type=file
    }]
```

I realized that the above config is not working. I have right now 1500 + application..log.gz files in my logging directory. I checked the log for the dropwizard FileAppenderFactory and found that the archivedFileCount is used to set the maxHistory for logback. based on logback documentation it should only keep 700 hours of archives. Service is able to rollover logs without any problem to log.gz files but the deletion of old files is not working. I am using dropwizard version 1.3.5.

Comment: any updates? we see the same issue

Comment: any solution for this? we see the same issue with our application.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the fact that **TimeBasedRollingPolicy** is not actually clock-based but rather event-driven. From their official [docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FixedWindowRollingPolicy):

> For various technical reasons, rollovers are not clock-driven but depend on the arrival of logging events.
> For example, on 8th of March 2002, assuming the fileNamePattern is set to yyyy-MM-dd (daily rollover), the arrival of the first event after midnight will trigger a rollover. If there are no logging events during, say 23 minutes and 47 seconds after midnight, then rollover will actually occur at 00:23'47 AM on March 9th and not at 0:00 AM. Thus, depending on the arrival rate of events, rollovers might be triggered with some latency.

Since you use an hourly rollover rate, a log file from the first hour will miss deletion if log events don't trigger for an hour; first 2 will get missed if events don't fire for 2 hours, etc.

```
log_hr1, log_hr2, no log events fire for hr3, log_hr4, log_hr5 (initiate rollover)

...

log_hr1, log_hr245, log_hr6
```

So, **log_hr1** gets missed.

To solve your problem, you can change your rollover rate to be daily so that you get a higher margin for error. However, this might introduce a second problem of individual log files getting too large. To avoid that, you can add the **maxFileSize** property and adjusted your rollover policy to be a SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy (add the %i flag to the log file name). For instance,

```
archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/example-%d-%i.log.gz
archivedFileCount: 5
maxFileSize: "10mb"
```

This essentially archives by date first but also limits the size of each log file. Each time the current log file reaches maxFileSize before the current time period ends, it will be archived with an increasing index, starting at 0. If our application is stopped and restarted, logging will continue at the correct location, i.e. at the largest index number for the current period. Note: this is all documented in Logback's official doc.

Hope this helped.